# How can I let user select the location for downloading an Export to Excel file in asp.net webforms?

Tags: asp.net, download, webforms, openfiledialog

I'm exporting an excel file that's created dynamically at run time from DataTables in aspx.cs file at server side using [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) lib. I want to let user select the downloading file location at client side, which is currently moved to downloads.

Comment: You cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

You unfortantly cannot do this. This is also why you can never select a local file or location from server side.

So, the users local file system is 100% off limits.

And the reason is quite simple. If you come to my web site to look at some cute cat picture? Well, while you are doing that, do you think it would be ok if my web code also starts looking around at your files? Hum, maybe a file called banking? Maybe a filel called passwords? Hum, how about I steal all your email files? How about I look for a Excel sheet called passwords?

So, when it comes to poking around, looking at, and deciding things like file locations? You cannot on the server side GET ANY information, nor can you even find and define what file to pick for up-loading, and the SAME applies to downloading of files. If I could pick a location, then gee, why don't I start overwriting some of your system files - including some that would give me remote access to your computer, right?

So, things like what folder, what file, even the computer name etc? These things are 100% hidden, off limits and simple not allowed. Now it would be possible for someone to come out with a new web browser tht allowed local file rights and access. But then again, no one in their right minds would ever use such a browser, and the security hole would be too large. As a result, for reasons of security, such information, and even simple knowledge of the local file system is not allowed, nor even exposed to the web server.

But then again, the user might be on a iPad, or android phone, and their file systems and how their folders works is not even the same as say a windows desktop computer anyway.

However, you can see with above, that your ability or even options to mess with, or even choose local file locations is not allowed for reasons of security.

So, if you web site provides a file, or even streams down a file, it will go into the download folder as per user browser settings - you unfortantly can't change this - it works that way due to security concerns.